# Xamarin Forms - How to have a view (ad) have a single instance over all pages?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to include banner ads in my application using xamarian forms. Assume I have a view of the ad and I want to place it in my app that is using navigation on iOS, Android, and UWP on all pages.

How can I get that ad view instance to be the same for all pages?

Preferably I do not want to reload the ad view per page but to rather have it exist through each page without being reloaded. I'm thinking that it could be one of two ways, one being always on the screen like the navigation bar where the content is rendered below the add, or the other way being a view is on every page but is loaded with a single instance across all pages.

Comment: I am not sure but you should use MasterDetailPage.Add common view in MasterDetail.

Comment: I know the following link is going to be a bit heavy handed for what you are asking but would be the only way to do it, that I am aware of. [This link](http://twintechs.com/advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-5-page-in-page-embedding/) by Twin Techs talks about embedding a page in another page and would allow highly customizable navigation (since you can basically fake your navigation transitions).

Comment: After several hours' research and test, I cannot use the original `NavigationPage` to achieve a page in which other pages can be embedded. A tricky method is not using the `NavigationPage` template but creating our own navi bar. Do you have any progress?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I was able to kinda get what I want by wrapping the tableview in a stack layout and placing my ad view first and then the tableview. This however is not persisting through page navigation. Each page has to have an ad view added as well and I get a new ad instead of maintaining the old one.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444, yes, this is exactly the same as I thought, we can only add views to pages in xamarin forms, this is why I said achieving this without `NavigationPage` template. I also cannot find any better method to create a control in forms like `FrameLayout` for fragment inflation in android, or `Frame` control for page navigation in UWP, and meanwhile has the ability to cooperate with the `NavigationPage`. But if we separatly use xamarin.android and xamarin.ios for development, there should be no such problem.

Comment: While I personally would do this via native renderers, via `Xamarin.Forms` you can use a "static" `View` and embed that into each `Page`.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm ok with using custom renderers. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good approach.

Go to App.xaml and declare the following resources:

```
...
<controls:AdViewControl AdUnitId="YOUR_UNIT_ID" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" 
                        HeightRequest="50" x:Key="AdViewControl1"/>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="AdOnFooterPage">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentView Content="{StaticResource AdViewControl1}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
...
```

The next is to link the ControlTemplate with the pages you want to display the Ad:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="BdvAssistant.Views.Recharge.RechargePage"
             Title="Page 1"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource AdOnFooterPage}">
...
```

**(This is optional)** If your navigation cache the pages, you will need to unlink the AdViewControl from the old parent (the ControlTemplate) and assign it to the new parent. Here is an example for MasterDetailPage, the following code should be adapted to MainPage.

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    private readonly Dictionary<MenuItemType, NavigationPage> _menuPages
        = new Dictionary<MenuItemType, NavigationPage>();
    
    private readonly Dictionary<MenuItemType, ContentView> _adContentViews
        = new Dictionary<MenuItemType, ContentView>();

    private AdViewControl AdControl => (AdViewControl)Application.Current.Resources["AdViewControl1"];

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    public async Task NavigateFromMenu(MenuItemType menu)
    {
        if (AdControl.Parent is ContentView parent)
            parent.Content = null;

        if (_menuPages.TryGetValue(menu, out var newPage))
        {
            if (_adContentViews.TryGetValue(menu, out var adParent))
                adParent.Content = AdControl;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (menu)
            {
                case MenuItemType.Dashboard:
                    newPage = new NavigationPage(new DashboardPage());
                    break;
                case MenuItemType.Security:
                    newPage = new NavigationPage(new PinManagerPage());
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }

            _adContentViews[menu] = AdControl.Parent as ContentView;
            _menuPages[menu] = newPage;
        }
        
        if (ReferenceEquals(Detail, newPage))
            return;
        
        Detail = newPage;

        if (MasterBehavior == MasterBehavior.Popover)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                await Task.Delay(200);

            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```